# Будет ли влиять на SEO продвижение, если в имени изображения стоит ".png.webp"?

Tags: изображения, seo

Сайт на Wordpress, плагин заменяет изображения на формат webp , подставляя в конце имени файла этот формат, то есть вконце изображения добавляется .webp, получается "image_name.png.webp" .
Влияет ли это как то на SEO ?

Answer (score 0):

Само появление расширения .webp никак не повлияет. Это всё равно что, если на машину прилепить шильдик turbo — турбина в машине не появится и быстрее ехать не станет. Так и здесь — то, что вы просто добавите расширение .webp не сделает файл меньше при том же качестве изображения, и никак не повлияет пока. А если помимо вас соберется еще толпа "умных" по мнению Google, то могут выпустить апдейт и подрежет позиции за "попытку манипуляции". Ну а если это действительно обработка изображения, то само расширение роли не играет. Играет обьём страницы, обьём файлов и оптимизация загрузки. Файлы меньше весят, загрузка оптимизирована потоковостью и т.д присутствует > profit!!!

Comment: Ну сам плагин, о котором говорится, скорее всего конвертирует изображение в webp формат иначе это было бы бесполезной вещью (просто в вопросе это паршиво объяснено, могу предположить что это [WebP Express](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/)) + плагинов которые просто добавляли бы расширение без конвертации, оставляя файл в том же формате, я не встречал.

Comment: Я за свои 10 лет SEO опыта понял одно — перепроверяй и ищи подвоха. И есть ньюансы:
1. WP плагин может залить практически любой и это не проблема.
2. Если к файлам .jpeg, .jpg и .png добавить в конце расширение .webp — вуаля, всё отрабатывается, всё работает. (другие не тестил, ведь эти самые популярные). Поэтому надо чекать, меняется ли вес файла
3. Формулировка главного вопроса, конечно, меня в первую очередь и сподвигла всё перепроверить  — простая смена расширения)))) Поэтому таков ответ

Comment: * Профдеформация — всегда что-то не так, поэтому люди могут написать одно, а я ищу совершенно другое. И чаще не безосновательно, к сожалению((((